# Angular - Anchor in-page-link - Flash Background

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have two divs/columns and on the left is a list of anchors and the right is the paragraphs of content. When the anchor (or div) is clicked, it will scroll to the appropriate content in the right column.

I want to go the extra mile and add a little flash to the background of the target so the user can find it more easily. I can use the following CSS to do that:

```
/* Highlight Background Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes highlight {
    0% {
        background-color: transparent;
        opacity:1;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: green;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}

.active{
  -webkit-animation-name: highlight;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name: highlight;
    -moz-animation-duration: 500ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

So anything with the class `.active` will flash for a moment. I'd like do use my Angular controller to find the target `id` and either add the `.active` class (and remove `.active` from all others) or somehow simulate that css background animation.

Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <left-column>
        <div class="large-12 column">
            <a href="#target1">Target 01</a>
        </div>

        <div class="large-12 column">
            <a href="#target2">Target 02</a>
        </div>

        <div class="large-12 column">
            <a href="#target3">Target 03</a>
        </div>
    </left-column>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <right-column>
        <div id="target1">
            <h3>Target 01</h3>
            <p>Stuff here</p>
        </div>
        <div id="target2">
            <h3>Target 02</h3>
            <p>Stuff here</p>
        </div>
        <div id="target3">
            <h3>Target 03</h3>
            <p>Stuff here</p>
        </div>
    </right-column>
</div>
```

**JS** *(currently empty)*

```
function homeCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
}
```

Comment: are the columns in isolated scope directives? Is there already a data model for these items?

Comment: The columns are in a directive called `<left-column></left-column>` and `<right-column></right-column>`. There is no data model.

Comment: *"There is no data model"* ... still seems like you are building this app backwards... creating the view then trying to figure out how to integrate angular features. The view should be driven by the data model. So you model the data first..then build the view to handle the data. For example all your items would be shared between both directives in array of objects and the view would repeat over them to provide either the links or the content sections

Comment: It's just a simple Q&A page. The content in the answers is sporadic, could be a sentence, a paragraph, a list. I could probably record the data as a complex .json file, but there's really no reason. I know hard coding it into the directive sounds dumb, but it's really just an html page with a little angular to make filtering things and scrolling nice.

Comment: Fine but then simple starts getting complex and by starting on wrong foot you end up not taking advantage of the framework and making things more difficult than they could be.

Comment: Even if I had a data model, the point is to get the target of the anchors' click. E.G., I click `<a href="target1">Target 01</a>` then the page will scroll to `<div id="target1"></div>`. And that's what I need angular to either flash the background of or add a class (then remove that class).

Comment: If there was a data model you could then use `ng-class` and set a `selectedItem` in the controller. Hard coding it you might just as well use dom methods. A simple directive on the links could be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was really tricky, but I got exactly the desired effect I wanted.

I had to use the `addClass` and `removeClass` methods of the `ngAnimate` API. So first I had to add the dependency:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
```

Next I used `ng-repeat` to create all the html and data I was using, while adding an `ng-click` to each `<a>` tag.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="topic in vm.data.topics" class="large-12 column">
    <a href="#{{ topic.tag }}" ng-click="vm.highlight(topic.tag)">{{ topic.title }}</a>
</div>
```

Next it was time to create the function in my controller:

**JS**

```
// Didn't forget to inject it!
homeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$animate'];
function homeCtrl($scope, $animate) {...


    vm.highlight = function(tag) {
        if (typeof vm.target !== 'undefined') {
            $animate.removeClass(vm.target, 'selected');
        }
        vm.target = angular.element(document.getElementById(tag));
        $animate.addClass(vm.target, 'selected');
    };


...}
```

And finally some CSS to create the nice background flash effect:

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes highlight {
    0% {
        background-color: transparent;
        opacity:1;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: rgba(64,64,64,0.2);
    }
    100% {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}

.selected {
  -webkit-animation-name: highlight;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name: highlight;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

***SUMMARY***

So the trick was to use `ngAnimate's` `addClass` and `removeClass` inside of an `ngClick` function passing the anchor link as a parameter so that it could properly find the correct target div with the same id (as the anchor link) thus changing the class while also removing the former divs class if need be so that the effect could be reproduced.